# Displaying the Value of a ViewBag in the EditorFor() method of a View using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

It is possibly a mistake in my syntax, but I have been unable to set a default value for my `EditorFor` in my view using `ViewBag`.

I have checked that the value in the `ViewBag.FirstName` is being passed through correctly, it is fine. However, the field displays with no value.

My statement is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } ,  @Value = ViewBag.FirstName })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Apologies for the simplicity of my question.

Comment: Why on earth would you do this (other than to make model binding fail). Set the value of your model property (not a `ViewBag`property)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should really just do model binding the normal way: by assigning the value of the model property. `ViewBag` is unmaintainable and not strongly-typed.

If you really *do* need `ViewBag` for some reason, just move your assignment to `@Value` inside your `htmlAttributes` object, like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = ViewBag.FirstName } })
```

Comment: Hi @johnnyRose, I have used this solution, though it is binding the data and showing it in the View but on Form Post I am getting null for that property. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AjendraPrasad: You should be using model binding both ways. Don’t use ViewBag - instead set the property you’re trying to bind to. If that doesn’t work, you’ll probably need to ask a new question, since the information you provided is limited.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old answer and thanks to johnnyRose for the correct one. I simply wanted to add that I was still not able to get the @value passed with it and it was because of the @Value a simple matter of case v=V.. Wanted to share my ignorance in hopes of helping another. :)